# Understanding natural parameterization of exponential family

Tags: distributions, expected-value, exponential-family, parameterization

I'm going through section 3.4 on exponential families in *Statistical Inference* by Casella and Berger. They first cite the following general form of an exponential family:

$$f(x|\mathbf{\theta})=h(x)c(\mathbf{\theta})\exp\left(\sum_{i=1}^k w_i(\mathbf{\theta})t_i(x)\right)\tag{1}$$

and then introduce the notion of the equivalent natural parameterization

$$f(x|\mathbf{\eta})=h(x)c^*(\mathbf{\eta})\exp\left(\sum_{i=1}^k \eta_it_i(x)\right)\tag{2}$$

with $h$ and $t_i$ the same as in the original parameterization. If $\eta$ yields a family with $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{f(x|\mathbf{\eta})}{c^*(\mathbf{\eta})}dx$ finite, then $\eta$ belongs to the so-called natural parameter space, and in this family we obviously have $c^*(\mathbf{\eta})=\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{f(x|\mathbf{\eta})}{c^*(\mathbf{\eta})}dx\right)^{-1}$. I have a couple questions which are blocking my ability to fully understand this reparameterization.

First, I know there are some useful mathematical properties of the natural parameterization, and every reference I've found so far discussing the exponential family (unless they are directly referring to the same book) introduce it in the natural parameterization instead of the origin one posed in the book. That begs the question whether this original parameterization is at all standard, what its benefits are, and why Casella and Berger introduced the exponential family with it instead of the natural parameterization like so many other references?

Now let's work with what's given in the book. I'm having trouble understanding how we can go from (1) to (2) with just a reparameterization; what is this reparameterization? According to [this](http://pages.stat.wisc.edu/%7Eshao/stat609/stat609-09.pdf) one way to obtain (2) from (1) is to let $\eta_i=w_i(\mathbf{\theta})$, which would make sense, but apparently this is only a subset of the natural parameter space $\mathcal{H}$? That makes it difficult for me to see how to obtain the natural parameter space since there doesn't seem to be any well-defined method of obtaining $\eta_i$ which fixes $c^*$. There is one exercise in the book (3.29) which asks to find the natural parameter space, and the solution manual just seems to find $\{\mathbf{\eta}=(w_1(\mathbf{\theta}),...,w_k(\mathbf{\theta})):\mathbf{\theta}\in\Theta\}$, which is apparently just a subset of $\mathcal{H}$. Can someone provide an example of an exponential family where $\mathcal{H}$ is in fact finer than $\{(w_i(\Theta))\}$? If they were equal then I wouldn't have any doubts, but I'm having trouble seeing the supposedly more general case.

Lastly, these doubts are blocking my ability to start tackling exercise 3.32 in the book. One part of the exercise is to show that a previously given identity:

$$E\left(\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{\partial w_i(\mathbf{\theta})}{\partial \theta_j}t_i(X)\right)=-\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_j}\log c(\mathbf{\theta})$$

under the original parameterization can be simplified to:

$$E(t_j(X))=-\frac{\partial}{\partial \eta_j}\log c^*(\mathbf{\eta})$$

under the natural parameterization. Given my lapses in understanding the connection between the two forms, and the concrete definitions of $\mathbf{\eta}$ and $c^*$ in the general case and how they connect to the original form, I'm not sure where to start in proving this simplification. Any insights in the perspective of solving this problem (the other parts are similar) would be greatly appreciated.